Iterating efficiently for sentence similarity matching in a dataframe
The dataframe (data_df) as 6M rows. The first four rows as follows. I need to calculate the semantic similarity between each src_sent with the rest and find the sentences with edit distance less than 10 and drop those rows. Simlarity I need to iterate the entire 6M and drop the most simlar sentences.
As most similar sentences I take the sentences having edit distance less than 10.

| src_sents                          | tgt_sents                 
-------- ----------------------------| ------------------------------
| Where is 2011 AG5 now?             | 2011 AG5 දැන් කොහෙද ඉන්නේ?  
| God knows what he’s saying.        | මේකා මොනව කියනවද කියල දෙයියො තමා දන්නෙ.                   
| but their heart is far from Me.    | එහෙත් ඔවුන්ගේ හදවත් මාගෙන් දුරස් වීඇත.                            
| But he obeyed his parent’s wishes. | අනෙක් අතට, ඔහු තම දෙමාපියන්ගේ ආශාව ඔහුට ගරු කළා      

To calculate the semantic simlarity I use Levenshtein edit distance. The calculation and iteration takes considerable time. How to efficiently do this?
Following is my code.
min_threshold=0
max_threshold=10

def get_Levenshtien_distance(text, ref_sentence):
    return levenshtein_distance(str(text), str(ref_sentence))

for idx, row in data_df.iterrows():
      current_sliced_df = df.drop(index=idx)
      current_sliced_df["Levenshtien_distance"] = df["src_sents"].apply(get_Levenshtien_distance, args=(ref_src_sent,))

      min_Levenshtien_distance_indexes = list(current_sliced_df.loc[(current_sliced_df["Levenshtien_distance"]>=min_threshold) & (current_sliced_df["Levenshtien_distance"]<=max_threshold)].index)


Appreciate any direction on how to improve this.

Not sure I got it right. Are you computing levenshtein distance between texts of two different languages? Is that possible? Are you translating first and then computing the distance?

Thank you for your interest. It would be to remove similar sentences in the same language. (column-wise iteration) (At a given time only En  or Sinhala sentences would be considered during the process)

Since you need to calculate similarity between each src_sent with the rest, i.e, every row with all others in a serie of 6 million records, that involve computing 6 * 6 million = 36 BILLION times the similarity in a for loop.
So, in any way, due to the amount of data, this operation takes a lot of time.
Now, if you can wait the time it takes for the loop to complete (again, it is many iterations), you can achieve your goal with this:
result = []
for ref_sentence in sentences_serie:
    filter_sim = [ other for other in sentences_serie if get_Levenshtien_distance(ref_sentence, other) < 10 ] 
    for others in filter_sim:
        #Make sure you don't store repeat pairs
        if tuple(sorted((ref_sentence, other)) ) not in result:
            result.append( tuple(sorted((ref_sentence, other) ) ) )

In "result", you get a list of tuples with pairs of sentences that meet the desired filter.
